# How to export data to an Excel 2007 table using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, dts, ssis

I have an excel file (xlsx) containing a table :

[image: Excel Table]

Once I launched my ssis task (successfully) to insert data in it, it is actually append after the table :

[image: Excel Table after the SSIS task]

My expected result:

[image: Expected]

So I am looking for a way to insert into the table and expand it with the data. I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer.
So I needed to generate excel reports with a lot of pivot charts linked to a main table.

But using a table was a bad idea. Instead, the pivot charts must be linked to a named range.

The last thing to know is that the error message "Invalid References" appears if the named range doesn't use the OFFSET function.

My named range formula is :

```
=OFFSET(Sheet!$A$1, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet!$A:$A), NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)
```

Where Sheet is the name of the worksheet and NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS is the number of columns of the data.

That's it. I can now generate excel report without any line of code, only using SSIS 2005.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use SSIS for this, you may have [Excel2007 as linked server](http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2009/02/excel-2007-linked-server.html) , putting data into Excel by regular TSQL,  or process data by Excel VBA getting data directly from SQL Server. As a matter of practical sanity, I [would not ever use SSIS for anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449344/alternatives-to-ssis)

Well, there is not much information how you do it but you should specify somehow that first row should not be used as header names container (HDR=NO), something like,

- insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
  'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls; ; **HDR=NO'**,
  'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')

Comment: I really need to use SSIS. I have found a way to insert data into an Excel table with C#, using the OpenXML SDK. But I am still looking for a way to do it directly into SSIS. I would be surprised it is not possible. Unfortunately, [WorksheetName].[TableName] doesn't work :( I'll post my finale solution, unless someone provide me a solution.

Comment: Yeaah, I did not work with Excel for quite a time but I remember that in 2007 it is possiblу to work directly with XML schema of underlying sheets data (what is not available in 2003)